# How to group values in a dataframe and keeping the values associated

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I am trying to solve a problem in Python, I feel like groupby is the solution but I can't tell how should I use it.

I have a dataframe `budget` where every team in the first league of soccer in France is associated with the budget of the team.

It looks like this

[DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtfcK.png)

The seasons go from '2010/2011' to '2019/2020'. I want to find a way to be able to GroupBy eachteamm with the budget associated for each season. I think I could do it by iterating through every columns and finding the index associated with the team value and finding what's the budget's value for each season. But maybe there's is a more efficient way that you could help me find.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the DB Schema, I would first extract data into separate dataframes for each year and have `df_year2011['Team','Budget','Year']`,`df_year2012['Team','Budget','Year']` ..and so on and so forth.

Than I would concat them to create a df :

```
 frames=[df_year2011,df_year2012,df_year2013]
 df = pd.concat(frames)
```

And than to group the data in the dataframe, I would apply this :

```
 df_grouped=df.groupby('Team')
```

And if you need to group by multiple columns you do :

```
df_grouped=df.groupby(['Column1_Name','Column2_Name'])
```

Comment: Thank you for you help, but I think that it doesn't do what I need. If I groupby with the column "1" for example I will get a DataFrame with : As Monaco, in 2010/2011 : 53 and 2019/2020 : 70 but I want to get 220 for 2019/2020

Comment: Ok column1 does not mean it has to be column1 precisely, it can be any columns you desire. In your case it would be the `df_grouped= df.groupby('Team')`
And than you can get the budget by simply invoking the budged column. `df_grouped['Budget']`

Comment: I think I understand how to use groupby in the case you mention. But, the teams in the columns 1,2,3... are not ranked the same. It is like this because the database ranks team by the biggest budget to the lowest. I uploaded a picture of the DB in case I make myself not very clear ...

Comment: I added changes to the answer based on what you provided, if you still have a question on how to split the data into a separate dataframes, let me know, probably you can write another question and I could answer that one as well.

Comment: If it answers your question, please do not forget to mark it as the correct answer, for benefit of other readers !